# Как сортировать файл и сравнить результат?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 2 одинаковых csv файла с множеством столбцов и строк, хочу найти в файл1 максимальное значению в столбце "сумма", затем обратиться с этим значением к файл2 и если есть совпадение вывести на экран. Как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если файлы одинаковые, то ничего делать не надо. Если файлы не одинаковые, то покажите свой код.

Comment: То что есть нельзя назвать кодом, мне бы логику понять, сортировать как массив или как список или по ключ-значение, я никогда еще не работал с файлами(

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то вы ищите максимальное значение в одном файле, а потом ищите это же значение в другом файле? Если да, то зачем? 
ЗЫ @strawdog, привет

Comment: Проверка на соответствие, один файл2 контрольный и по нему сверяю значения. Хочу прокачать такой скилл.
`file = ['1','7','4','2']
file2 = ['1', '4', '6', '8','5']
#file = sorted(file)
result = [x for x in file2 if x in file]`

Comment: Непонятно задание, вы хотите сравнить весь файл или только одно значение из столбца, или весь столбец

Comment: Я хочу найти в файле столбец и найти в этом столбце наксимальное значение.

Comment: @offline воспользуйтесь модулем pandas. Вы существенно облегчите себе жизнь. Если хотите конкретного ответа, приведите примеры исходных данных.

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Тут два выхода либо воспользоваться Pandas или если вы хотите своим способом через sort, то вам нужно вытащить последний элемент file[-1], а дальше делайте что хотите

Comment: В вашем случае может только метод проб и ошибок, удачи

Comment: Если вы приводите код или пример данных в виде картинок, будьте готовы к нерабочим (непроверенным) ответам или к отсутствию таковых вообще ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на [вопрос из комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/999951/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82/999974#comment1691671_999951):

> Я хочу найти в файле столбец и найти в этом столбце наксимальное
>   значение.

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=",")

col_name = "Balance"

col_max = df[col_name].max()

print(col_max)
```